# POST not working for remote server, on localhost works

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have program, which is calling API in different solution. When I host API on localhost (while VS debug) all works fine. But, when I publish API project on the server and try to call POST method on it from my client app, I have 404 Error. At the same time, when I call other methods on this endpoints (GET, PUT, etc) - all works. Only POST doesn't work on server.

I checked URL in Postman, and POST method works fine in Postman.

**In client app calling code looks like this:**

```
                            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("URL_HERE", element, jsonformatter);
                        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            // code removed

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // code removed
                        }
```

**This is response I've got:**

```
{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Wed, 01 Apr 2020 07:20:48 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Expires: -1
}}
```

**Response when API hosted on localhost (or call from Postman for API hosted on server):**

```
{StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Date: Wed, 01 Apr 2020 08:23:53 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
}}
```

**Code in API:**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<ElementType>> Post([FromBody] ElementType Element)
{
    //code removed
}
```

I checked if it is issue with SSL, I turned it on/off on server and project, but no changes.

Comment: There could be various reasons for this. Probably the first place to look at would be the IIS log. Please enable logging on the API/website and inspect.

Comment: This is I got from log: ``2020-04-01 07:25:09 172.16.1.21 POST /api/votingdata - 443 - 10.16.2.20 PostmanRuntime/7.24.0 - 415 0 0 109
2020-04-01 07:01:10 172.16.1.21 POST /api/votingdata - 443 - 172.16.1.21 - - 404 0 0 78``

Comment: sorry i can't spot any from this

Comment: @Nair I see and understand. Is there any way to get more log from IIS than this? Or is this everything I can get?

Comment: Fiddler is another tool to see the request/response from browser. Postman also has some profile log (i don't remember the name correctly). The log from Fiddler and post man then can be compared each other. This would give you some idea about what is the difference between requesting directly to IIS and when requested from postman. Extra log can be captured in IIS. If you go into website/api virtual directory and enable logs / or capture it to a txt file. If you don't know the step then google it since there are lot of example on how to capture IIS log.